# Get max(id) and all values as array from database, MYSQl and PHP

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to get the max(id) of the table and also all the values inside the table in one array. what ever I am trying gets me the details of the max(id) row but I am looking for whole table in one query.

mysql:

```
SELECT *, MAX(id) FROM table1 ORDER BY name ASC;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with,

```
SELECT *, 
(Select MAX(id) from table1)

FROM table1 ORDER BY name ASC;
```